# Include and require doesnt work with Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed Xampp, which from what i can tell is working properly, and put 2 files in htdocs folder:

File1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>


<body>

<?php
include "skrypt.php";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

File2:

```
<?php
echo "<p>test php</p>";
?>
```

But when i'm opening first file in browser it is blank. I tried it with require, "/skrypt.php" and "../skrypt.php" instead with same result.

Comment: if you try with 'require' does php return some errors?

Comment: `require("skrypt.php");` - Remove the leading forward-slash (assuming your files are in the same folder).

Comment: Page is always blank, regardles of what i type in html file. I tried it without slash at first, with same result.

Comment: If it's an HTML file, then the PHP will never be executed. Are you use it's a `.php`?

Comment: The first file is .html, should it be .php ? Edit: yep, seems so, i suspected that im making some stupid mistake.

Comment: Yes, it should be a PHP file. If it's just an HTML file, then that file will be sent to your browser, exactly as it is. If it's a PHP file, however, anything within `<?php ?>` tags will be parsed.

Comment: Yes - that's the right answer. It will not be parsed as php unless it ends with .php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Jordan Hugh McKimm suggested iv made simple mistake by attempting to run php code in .html file instead of .php

Answer (score 0):

When troubleshooting, this PHP snippet is very helpful (especially with xdebug installed)

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Your path to skyrpt.php is likely going to be incorrect, but that snippet above will let you know for sure.

If the path *is* correct, then it will be a permissions issue.

Comment: where should i insert this code ? putting it inside either file does absolutely nothing.

Comment: at the very top of either file. Inside of `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/skrypt.php";
```